# Why is my browser text suddenly small?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

So I have not made any changes, but the text in my browser (e.g. on YouTube) now seems smaller than usual (see the "sign in" button on the image below)

[image]

I have checked settings in Chrome and the zoom size is at 100% and font size is also "Medium (Recommended)"

I've checked another browser (Internet Explorer) and the text size seems around about the same (smaller)

Is there a simple change I could have inadvertently made?

Comment: Perhaps your display DPI settings? This may have changed with graphics driver updates, or potentially you may have accidentally changed it.

Comment: Pressing Ctrl while rolling the mouse wheel?